# AngularJS Use Same Component In same Page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I use angularjs first time.
I'm tring to use same search component twice in page. but in the second component modal.show is not working!

Here is my code.

my button click code.
Where i click a modal will show.

```
$scope.openTalepIsEmriList = function (talepUN) {
                a.talepisemrilistesi = [];
                $("#divTalepIsEmriListesiModal").modal("show");
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/api/CrmTalepHareket/TalepIsEmriListesi?talepUN=' + talepUN,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                })
                    .then(
```

and in the page i call the component

first :

```
 <talep-ara-tum container-id="abonearama"  kullanici-id="modelTalep.Kullanici.ID" abonemodel="Aboneler" aramadanmi="true" talepler="aratalepmodel" kullaniciisletme="kullaniciisletme"></talep-ara-tum>
```

second:

```
<div class="row">
<talep-ara-tum kullanici-id="modelTalep.Kullanici.ID" abonemodel="Aboneler" 
aramadanmi="false" talepmodel="AboneSahisTalepleri" kullaniciisletme="kullaniciisletme"></talep-ara-tum></div>
```

Comment: this likely happens because the two components share the same id.

Comment: yes probobly that is the reason but what is the solution:)

Comment: It largely depends on one question only: what is the reason behind using the same component twice with the same id?

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because of the two components sharing the same ID, you could change one of them to the same but add a 2 or change it to hardcoded ID's first and see if that works. I can't really read what it says, I can't read Turkish(?). Didn't know you could change the language of AngularJS.

Comment: Thanks for respond.  yes it's turkish :) 
<talep-ara-tum> this is my component name.
you can think like that.

<search container-id="test" searchAll='false' > like these..

<search container-id="test" searchAll='true' >

Comment: Okay, could you change the id to test and the other to test2 or something. That could work.

Comment: Could you add a jsFiddle or something where I can try your code? I think it's a small thing, maybe a typo.

Comment: Yes we changed the id. but we sent id from the page to component. and set id dynamicly in component. and solved. thanks.

Comment: Great that you figured it out. No problem!